# Can log level be changed for sbt plugin, say sbt-idea?

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-idea

I'm using the [sbt-idea](https://github.com/mpeltonen/sbt-idea) plugin and in my metaproject and main project, I have a setting for `logLevel := Level.Warn`. This is effective at silencing all sub-warning messages from most of my build, but `sbt-idea` keeps printing out `info` messages.

I'm guessing that perhaps the plugin gets loaded before `logLevel` is applied, and it somehow gets a reference to a logger with a different level? The plugin in particular doesn't seem to be doing anything particularly funky about logging, except that it does seem [to ask the state for its logger at initialization](https://github.com/mpeltonen/sbt-idea/blob/988e6fb80d8ee7a5312f41f087c84eca3f12e598/src/main/scala/org/sbtidea/SbtIdeaPlugin.scala#L103). It might end up being a different logger object from the one after my settings get applied?

I can't figure out what part of sbt actually consumes the `logLevel` setting key to see whether it creates a new logger or mutates the existing one.

Answer (score 2):

Use `--warn` or `--error` before `gen-idea`.

```
$ sbt --warn gen-idea
```

or

```
$ sbt --error gen-idea
```

See [Change the logging level globally](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.1/docs/Howto/logging.html#level) for more up-to-date info (pun intended).

Be careful, though, as you may really miss `info`s after you silence the `gen-idea` command as it may take a while to complete and *nothing* gets printed out in the meantime.

It may hence be more useful to use another trick and execute `warn` or `error` commands before `gen-idea`.

```
$ sbt warn gen-idea
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/jacek/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[info] Set current project to aaa (in build file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/stackoverflow/16256180/)
```

With this, you'll see *something* printed out on the console that may or may not be of some help.